# dotnet test - exit code 0 when test project doesn't compile

Tags: c#, cmd, asp.net-core, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity to build my .NET Core project and `dotnet test` with xunit to run tests.

My build is configured to fail if any tests fail, and this works fine if a test fails, but when the test project doesn't compile the exit code ends up being zero.

I believe this is because I run `dotnet test` in the folder that contains the test-directories like this: `for /f %%%a in ('dir /b /s project.json') do dotnet test %%%a`.

Looking at the log I can see the individual jobs that do not compile return with exit code 1, but the build step itself returns with exit code 0.

How can I make the exit code from the failed compilation attempts propagate down to the build step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a separate step in TC to just compile target test project, and then run tests without compilation (using no-build option) in next step (if all previous steps were successful).

```
--no-build
Does not build the test project prior to running it.
```